# How to read from multiple FASTA files with R?

Tags: r, fasta

I have the following problem: I have 10 different FASTA files with thousand sequences inside each file. I would like to read from each fasta file all the sequence and then (with paste) create a one big file with all the sequences.

My question is the following: how can I read from different files in the same time?

I tried:

```
a<-list.files()
```

and then

```
for (x in a) { temp<-read.table(x) seq<-summary(temp) print (seq)
```

but it doesn't work properly. I tried also the command read.fasta but it gives to me a strange output (not all the sequence)

Thank you very much for your help, it will be very appreciate!

Fabio

PS. I started to work with R just one week ago...so please, be patient even if it is a stupid question!

Comment: if you don't get help here, maybe try your question on the Bioconductor mailing list (pointing out that you are cross-posting from StackOverflow).

Comment: Can you successfully import a single file? Why are there no `;` or new lines between commands?

Answer (score 4):

[Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) has many packages for working with DNA sequences. Install the ShortRead package with

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("ShortRead")
```

Load the library and consult the help page for readFasta

```
library(ShortRead)
?readFasta
```

Figure out a pattern (like `list.files`) that matches the fasta files you want to read in, and read all fasta files matching the pattern into a single object

```
patt <- "fasta$"
fasta <- readFasta("/my/directory/containing/fasta/files", patt)
```

Then write the object out

```
writeFasta(fasta, "my_destination.fasta")
```

But actually R would not be the right tool for just concatenating files; likely you want to do more interesting things, some of which might be described in the vignettes for ShortRead, Biostrings, and GenomicRanges

```
browseVignettes("ShortRead")
browseVignettes("Biostrings")
browseVignettes("GenomicRanges")
```

The [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) is the best place to get support for Bioconductor packages.

Comment: Thank you very much. However instead of readFasta...I used the command apply (lapply(myseqs, function(x), read.fasta(x)).